# Unable to show Data on pdf in Dynamic Report

Tags: java, pdf-generation, ofbiz, dynamic-reports

Here I used a delegator to fetch data from a database and I am using the `ofbiz` framework.

Source Code that generates pdf:

```
public static String createTransactionSummaryReport(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

    Delegator delegator = (Delegator)request.getAttribute("delegator");
    String accountName = request.getParameter("accountName");

    JasperReportBuilder report = report();

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    //OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    report.columns(
           Columns.column("AccountName", "accountName", DataTypes.stringType()),
           Columns.column("Amount", "amount", DataTypes.bigDecimalType()),
           Columns.column("DebitAmount", "debitAmount", DataTypes.bigDecimalType()),
           Columns.column("CreditAmount", "creditAmount", DataTypes.bigDecimalType())
    ).title(Components.text("Transaction Summary Details"))
    .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())
    .setDataSource(getCollectionData(delegator, accountName))
    .show();
    /*try {
        report.show();
        //report.toPdf(out);
    } catch(DRException ex) {
        ex.getCause().printStackTrace();
    }*/
    return "success";
}

private static JRDataSource getCollectionData(Delegator delegator, String accountName) {

    List<TransactionSummaryDataProvider> dataList = new ArrayList<TransactionSummaryDataProvider>();

    List<GenericValue> accTgTransaDetails = null;

    try {
        accTgTransaDetails =  delegator.findByAnd("AcctgTransEntrySums", UtilMisc.toMap("accountName",accountName));
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(GenericValue eachData : accTgTransaDetails) {

        String accName = eachData.getString("accountName");
        BigDecimal amount = eachData.getBigDecimal("amount");
        BigDecimal debitAmount = eachData.getBigDecimal("debitAmount");
        BigDecimal creditAmount = eachData.getBigDecimal("creditAmount");

        dataList.add(new TransactionSummaryDataProvider(accName, amount, debitAmount, creditAmount));
    }

    return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);
}
```

**Bean Class:**

```
public class TransactionSummaryDataProvider {

    private String accountName;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private BigDecimal debitAmount;
    private BigDecimal creditAmount;

    public TransactionSummaryDataProvider(String accountName, BigDecimal amount, BigDecimal debitAmount, BigDecimal creditAmount) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.debitAmount = debitAmount;
        this.creditAmount = creditAmount;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public BigDecimal getDebitAmount() {
        return debitAmount;
    }

    public void setDebitAmount(BigDecimal debitAmount) {
        this.debitAmount = debitAmount;
    }

    public BigDecimal getCreditAmount() {
        return creditAmount;
    }

    public void setCreditAmount(BigDecimal creditAmount) {
        this.creditAmount = creditAmount;
    }
}
```

`.show()` method throws `InvocationTargetException`

How can I solve this problem?

In the `dataList` there are required data but those data are not displayed in the pdf.

Comment: I think the `show()` will work when you call it from a `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

For a better experience ask such questions in the user ml of the Apache OFBiz project, see here how to connect to more OFBiz experts: https://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html